Расстояния между объектами

Постоянно приходиться высчитывать по x и по y относительно высоты объектов...
Как возможно выровнять объекты между собой, по x и по y. Мол указать что расстояние по y должно равняться 5px так же по x. Есть какой то более практичный способ?
Вроде ровно все, в html вставляю и вижу что расстояние между объектами по y больше чем по x.
